# reverse tunneling

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, tunneling, reverse-proxy

for simplicity ill give my servers name, `server-A, server-B`

- `server-A` - a simple server **with public IP**, this server is 1G ram, shared CPU
- `server-B` - a more robust server with more ram, cpu cores etc..., **but it does not have public IP**, it goes through a router that I have no access to, so I cant do port forwarding for that server

I want to run a service on `server-B` so people will be able to connect to it, and the heavy calculations of that service will run on `server-B`

because I cant do port forwarding to `server-B` I am wondering if there is any network service that I can do something like reverse shell, `server-B` will be the one to initiate the connection to `server-A` and create a tunnel, then `server-A` will forward traffic to the tunnel initiated by `server-B`

at the end, people will connect to `server-A` on some port (8080 for example), `server-A` will take that request and forward it to `server-B` with a tunnel they share

is it possible

**note**
they are not in the same LAN, they are in completely different locations, `server-B` can reach directly to `server-A` with the internet, but `server-A` cant reach `server-B` directly

Comment: server-A has network access to server-B?

Comment: no, server-B can reach server-A, but not the otherway around, they are not in the same LAN or anything like that

Comment: can you do ssh to server-A from server-B?

Comment: yes, server-B can ssh to server-A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do SSH remote port forwading if enabled on server-A.

Run this command on server-B

```
ssh -R Server-A-port:127.0.0.1:server-B-port -N -f user@Server-A
```

So now any request hit on `server-A:Server-A-port` it will be passed to `server-B:server-B-port`

you can read more about ssh forwading [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling).

Comment: thanks, ill check it tomorrow